# Web API2 identity2 bearer token permission change

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity-2

Using Owin + Oauth2 + Identity2.

I have a web Api with default basic authentication setup that i have modified.

my startup.cs partial class

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);//TODO: prob wont need this

        // Configure the application for OAuth based flow
        PublicClientId = "self";

        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),//TODO: prob wont need this
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            // In production mode set AllowInsecureHttp = false
            AllowInsecureHttp = true //TODO: set debug mode
        };

        // Token Generation
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
    }
```

my startup.cs class partial at the root

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

        ConfigureAuth(app);

        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
```

my applicationOAuthProvider.cs

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        //get user
        var service = new CarrierApi.CarrierManagementClient();
        var result = service.LoginAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);
        var user = result.Result.Identity;

        //TODO: log stuff here? i.e lastlogged etc?

        if (user == null)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            return;
        }

        ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = user;
        ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = user;

        AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.GetUserName());
        AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
        context.Validated(ticket);
        context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
    }
```

As you can see i actually go and get the identity via a wcf call to our existing DB.  when using postman, i get the /token url and obtain my bearer token, on the next request i pass it into the header and call my controller method.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Templates_Access")]
    public string Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
        return "woo";
    }
```

This works great, if the user has the permission it wont allow access, if they do it does.

However if i go to our website that uses the same wcf and DB and change a users permission,  if i send the same request on postman it still allows access even though ive removed that permission on the role the user is assigned too.

How do i make sure that permissions are "refreshed" or checked again on each request?

Comment: You want to call out to your WCF service for every single request that gets made?

Comment: well i need to check permissions, which is set on the db, the wcf is the only access to our db.  basically i need a way to just check permissions havent changed, if they have then update the session or whatever so that authorization works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every roles of a user logged in are stored in the bearer token at login time as claim, in the GrantResourceOwnerCredentials method. If a request have to be authorized, the role is searched on the list stored in the bearer token by the default implementation of AuthorizationFilter; so if you change the user's permissions, you need a new login.

This behavior respects the Stateless contraint of a Restfull architecture, as Fielding wrote in his [dissertation](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_3), and also this is a good balance between performance and security

If you need a different behavior there is more than one possibility.

**Refresh Token**

You Can use Refresh Token, implementing the GrantRefreshToken method of applicationOAuthProvider class; you can retrieves the refreshed user's permissions and create a new access token; this is a good article to learn [how](https://leastprivilege.com/2013/11/15/adding-refresh-tokens-to-a-web-api-v2-authorization-server/).

Keep in mind:

- more complexity on client
- no real time effect; you have to wait the access Token expiring
- If the Access Token has a short life, you have to update it often (even when the user permissions are not changed) otherwise a long life does not solve the problem

**Check Permissions each request**

You can implement a custom AuthorizationFilter and check in the database the permissions of the user, but it is a slow solution.

**Cache and Login Session**

You can generate a user session's key (like a guid) for each login in the GrantResourceOwnerCredentials method, and store it in the bearer token as a claim. You have to store it also in a cache system (like Redis), using two index: the user session's key and the userId. The official documentation of Redis explains [how](https://redis.io/topics/indexes).

When the permessions of a user are changed, you can invalidate every sessions of that user in the cache system, searching by userId

You can implement a custom AuthorizationFilter and check for each request in cache if the session is valid, searching by user session's key.

*Be careful: this will violate the stateless constraint and your architecture will not restfull*

---

Here you can find the standard implementation of [AuthorizaAttribute filter](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/AuthorizeAttribute.cs). 
You can create your custom filter extending AuthorizeAttribute and overriding the IsAuthorized method.

Most likely there are other ways, but how often are changed the permissions of a user? In many systems, also in systems where the security is the first requirement, if the permissions's configuration of a user is changed during an active session, it is necessary a new login to active the new one.
Are you sure you needs to modify this standard behavior?

If you are, I suggest the solution with a cache system.

Comment: thankyou for the information, so your saying point identity to a cache layer, then authorization filter should make a call to cache to check

Comment: what about refresh token? does that go and call identity again to update results?

Comment: You have to implement by yourself the refresh token's mechanism, so you can refresh the user's permissions. I'll edit my answer to be more detailed.